# how to change the default video capture resolution in windows phone 8,8.1

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want build an app that will give users options to choose the resolution size of video recording (such as full HD-1920x1080 or vga-640x480 etc.)

I am using the code below but when I run this on 720p emulator, it shows the message which is in else part i.e. camera not support this. (when I change the value 800,450 , to 640 ,480 camera start working normally)

```
try
           {
              //string deviceName = DeviceStatus.DeviceName;
               //var deviceName = DeviceStatus.DeviceName;
               //if (deviceName.Contains("RM-885"))
               //{
                   Windows.Foundation.Size initialResolution = new Windows.Foundation.Size(800, 450);
                   Windows.Foundation.Size previewResolution = new Windows.Foundation.Size(800, 450);
                   Windows.Foundation.Size captureResolution = new Windows.Foundation.Size(800, 450);
                   if (AudioVideoCaptureDevice.AvailableSensorLocations.Contains(CameraSensorLocation.Back))
                   {
                       pops = await AudioVideoCaptureDevice.OpenAsync(CameraSensorLocation.Back, initialResolution);
                       await pops.SetPreviewResolutionAsync(previewResolution);
                       await pops.SetCaptureResolutionAsync(captureResolution);    


                   }
               }
          // }

           catch (Exception p) { Debug.WriteLine(p.Message); }

            try
            {
                if(pops != null)
                {


                    // create the videobrush for the viewfinder
                    videoRecordBrush = new VideoBrush();
                    videoRecordBrush.SetSource(pops);
                    // display the viewfinder image 
                    viewfinderRectangle.Fill = videoRecordBrush;
                    //shows available resolution message 
                    MessageBox.Show("statrt recording ");
                    MessageBox.Show(pops.PreviewResolution.ToString());
                    MessageBox.Show(pops.CaptureResolution.ToString());


                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("camera not support this ");
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("exception" + ex);
            }
        }
```

Is this right code to change the resolution in  video mode? or is there any other method?

Answer (score 4):

In Windows Phone 8.1, u can change the *aspect ratio* of both **video preview** and **captured photo** by changing the *MediaCapture.VideoDeviceController* setting.

Video preview is the view of camera you can see from your screen before you actually capture a photo. It is essential for the **aspect ratio** of video preview and captured photo to be the same to **avoid weird lines & black bars** in the captured photo. In other words, it is to ensure the photo captured to be exactly the same as the preview you see on the screen.

First, you can check all the available resolutions in your Windows Phone 8.1. In the following code, I demonstrate how to **check resolutions available** for video preview & captured photo. The height&width returned is the resolutions available for your phone, e.g at i=0, height=1080, width=1920 (1920x1080). Please debug at the height&width line to check for different resolution.

```
MediaCapture mediacapture = new MediaCapture();
await mediacapture.InitializeAsync(new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings{});
var previewResolution = mediacapture.VideoDeviceController.GetAvailableMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview);
var photoResolution = mediacapture.VideoDeviceController.GetAvailableMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.Photo);

        VideoEncodingProperties allResolutionsAvailable;
        uint height, width;
  //use debugger at the following line to check height & width for video preview resolution
        for (int i = 0; i < previewResolution.Count; i++)
        {
            allResolutionsAvailable = previewResolution[i] as VideoEncodingProperties;
            height = allResolutionsAvailable.Height;
            width = allResolutionsAvailable.Width;
        }
  //use debugger at the following line to check height & width for captured photo resolution
        for (int i = 0; i < photoResolution.Count; i++)
        {
            allResolutionsAvailable = photoResolution[i] as VideoEncodingProperties;
            height = allResolutionsAvailable.Height;
            width = allResolutionsAvailable.Width;
        }
```

After checking all the available resolutions from the *height* and *width* parameter above, you can **select the particular resolutions** you want by using .ElementAt(int) method, e.g. .ElementAt(0)

```
var selectedPreviewResolution = mediacapture.VideoDeviceController.GetAvailableMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview).ElementAt(1);
var selectedPhotoResolution = mediacapture.VideoDeviceController.GetAvailableMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.Photo).ElementAt(1);

await mediacapture.VideoDeviceController.SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview, selectedPreviewResolution);
await mediacapture.VideoDeviceController.SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync(MediaStreamType.Photo, selectedPhotoResolution);

//in .xaml <CaptureElement Name="viewfinder"/>
viewfinder.Source = mediacapture;
//to set video preview upright
mediacapture.SetPreviewRotation(VideoRotation.Clockwise90Degrees);
await mediacapture.StartPreviewAsync();
```

Set .ElementAt(i) for Video Preview & Captured Photo separately at the same aspect ratio.
Below are the resolutions available for Nokia Lumia 1520.

**Video Preview**

- i.....height*width..aspect ratio
- 0.....1080*1920....16:9
- 1......720*1280.....16:9
- 2......450*800.......16:9
- 3....1080*1440......4:3
- 4......768*1024......4:3
- 5......480*640........4:3

**Captured photo**

- i.... height*width..aspect ratio
- 0.... 3024*4992.......4:3
- 1.....1936*2592...162:121
- 2.....1536*2048.......4:3
- 3......480*640..........4:3
- 4.....3024*5376.....16:9
- 5.....1728*3072.....16:9
- 6.....1456*2592...162:91

Lastly, if you want to **use the maximum resolution** available for both Video Preview & Captured Photo, you can use the following code instead.

```
//maximum resolution for 4:3 aspect ratio 
 var maxPhotoResolution = mediacapture.VideoDeviceController.GetAvailableMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.Photo).Aggregate((i1, i2) => (i1 as VideoEncodingProperties).Height > (i2 as VideoEncodingProperties).Height ? i1 : i2);
 var maxPreviewResolution = mediacapture.VideoDeviceController.GetAvailableMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview).Aggregate((i1, i2) => (i1 as VideoEncodingProperties).Height > (i2 as VideoEncodingProperties).Height ? i1 : i2);

//maximum resolution for 16:9 aspect ratio 
 var maxPhotoResolution = mediacapture.VideoDeviceController.GetAvailableMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.Photo).Aggregate((i1, i2) => (i1 as VideoEncodingProperties).Width > (i2 as VideoEncodingProperties).Width ? i1 : i2);
 var maxPreviewResolution = mediacapture.VideoDeviceController.GetAvailableMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview).Aggregate((i1, i2) => (i1 as VideoEncodingProperties).Width > (i2 as VideoEncodingProperties).Width ? i1 : i2);

await mediacapture.VideoDeviceController.SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync(MediaStreamType.Photo, maxPhotoResolution);
await mediacapture.VideoDeviceController.SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview, maxPreviewResolution);
```

Comment: Similarly, the aspect ratio of the video record stream should match the aspect ratio of the video preview stream, so that the preview doesn't become distorted while recording.

Answer (score 1):

If you want more control over the recorded video, you should use the new Windows Phone 8 API: [AudioVideoCaptureDevice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.phone.media.capture.audiovideocapturedevice%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) which has a [SetCaptureResolutionAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.phone.media.capture.audiovideocapturedevice.setcaptureresolutionasync%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) method.

Comment: AudioVideoCaptureDevice class ,SetCaptureResolutionAsync method ,are used in my above code , but still not getting required resolution like 1920x1080 , it shows default resolution ie. 640x480

Comment: In which Device are You testing ? It may Depend on camera/Device Resolution. Just check it out

Comment: i am using  windows phone 720p emulator, on hyper-v.