# WP8.1RT: Custom resolution image taken from mediacapture C#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps

I'm having a little hard time after navigating around the site to find out solution. The problem I have is that I'm trying to capture an image using mediacapture taken from this [url](https://dzone.com/articles/how-capture-photo-your-windows-0) (download [here](http://msicc.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/MediaCaptureWithPreviewElement.zip)).

I've found a couple threads in SO that deal with resolution already, but what they're doing is using default resolution as following

```
3024*4992.......4:3
1936*2592...162:121
1536*2048.......4:3
480*640..........4:3
3024*5376.....16:9
1728*3072.....16:9
1456*2592...162:91
```

(suggeted by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24014566/how-to-change-the-default-video-capture-resolution-in-windows-phone-8-8-1))

However what I want is to capture an image with 800x600 resolution, is this really possible somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 800x600 only if your camera supports it. My camera for example doesn't.

Find available resolutions:

```
uint[] x_res; // available horizontal resolutions
uint[] y_res; // available vertical resolutions
uint resolutionwidth; //used horizontal resolution
uint resolutionheight; //used vertical resolution

private void get_res_button_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    resolution_listbox.Items.Clear();
    IEnumerable<VideoEncodingProperties> available_resolutions = captureManager.VideoDeviceController.GetAvailableMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.Photo).Select(x => x as VideoEncodingProperties);
    int total_res = available_resolutions.Count();
    x_res = new uint[total_res];
    y_res = new uint[total_res]
    int i = 0;
    foreach (VideoEncodingProperties resolution in available_resolutions)
    {
        x_res[i] = resolution.Width;
        y_res[i] = resolution.Height;
        resolution_listbox.Items.Add(x_res[i].ToString() + "  x  " + y_res[i].ToString());
        i++;
    }
}
```

Select the one you want:

```
private async void resolution_listbox_selectionchanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (resolution_listbox.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        int j = resolution_listbox.SelectedIndex;
        resolutionwidth = x_res[j];
        resolutionheight = y_res[j];
    }
// And apply it:
    IReadOnlyList<IMediaEncodingProperties> resolutions = captureManager.VideoDeviceController.GetAvailableMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.Photo);
    for (int k = 0; k < resolutions.Count; k++)
    {
        if (resolutions[k] is VideoEncodingProperties)
        {
            VideoEncodingProperties vidprops = (VideoEncodingProperties)resolutions[k];
            // check which VideoEncodingProperties contains the correct resolution
            if (vidprops.Width == resolutionwidth && vidprops.Height == resolutionheight)
            {
                await captureManager.VideoDeviceController.SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync(MediaStreamType.Photo, resolutions[k]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note:in the 1st method I used *IEnumerable< VideoEncodingProperties >* . This because I only want the numbers.

In the 2nd method I used *IReadOnlyList< IMediaEncodingProperties >*. This is because only the *VideoEncodingProperties* which contains the wanted resolution, needs to be applied. Not every *IMediaEncodingProperties* contains resolution information.

Comment: Very clear and precise, thank you! Fo you happen to know if it's possible to crop, expand inage taken afterward?

Comment: You're welcome.  I do not know if images can be cropped. Never looked at it.